# Facebook C# SDK + MVC3

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to implement the facebook login on my site and I am having some problems.

**Problems:**

I tried to follow the steps in http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Documentation but I got stuck on adding the references as I encounter "Unable to find assembly references that are compatible with the target framework '>NETFramework, Version=v4.0"... error on VS2010.

So, I downloaded the sample mvc3 project hoping that I can start and follow the steps from there, but I don't see the button on http://localhost:14567/Account/Login.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: The button shows on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE7 and IE8. But in both Chrome and Firefox I always get FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() == false after logging in to facebook's dialog.

UPDATE: I finally got it working based on the downloadable samples and assemblies from facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/78901 (I'll post this update as an answer later - I'm new to stackoverflow and I still have to wait for 5 more hours before I can answer my own question)

Comment: you can use nuget to download the facebook binaries. http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working based on the downloadable samples and assemblies from facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/78901 (I'll post this update as an answer later - I'm new to stackoverflow and I still have to wait for 5 more hours before I can answer my own question)